# Symfony Twig Extension breaks other service - Is templating done before security?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 WebApp. One of the bundles I created includes a service that offer some user related stuff, e.g. `userHasPurchases()`.

Problem is, that including a `Twig Extesion` breaks another service:

**AppShopService**

```
namespace AppShopBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
...

class AppShopService {
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, ...) {
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken() ? $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;
        ...
    }

    public function userHasPurchases(User $user) {
        $user = $user ? $user : $this->user;
        $result = $user...
        return result;
    }
}
```

**AppShopBundle\Resources\config\services.yml**

```
services:
    app_shop.service:
        class: AppShopBundle\Service\AppShopService
        arguments: 
            - "@security.token_storage"
            - ...
```

So far everything works fine: The `AppShopServices` is created with the current user and `userHasPurchases()` work as expected.

Now I have add a **Twig Extension** to be able to use `userHasPurchases()` within my templates:

**Twig Extension**

```
namespace AppShopBundle\Twig;

use AppShopBundle\Service\AppShopService;

class AppShopExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    private $shopService;

    public function __construct(AppShopService $shopService) {
        $this->shopService = $shopService;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_shop_bundle_extension';
    }

    public function getFunctions() {
        $functions = array();

        $functions[] = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('userHasPurchases', array(
                $this,
                'userHasPurchases'
            ));

        return $functions;
    }

    public function userHasPurchases($user) {
        return $this->shopService->userHasPurchases($user);
    }
}
```

**Including Extension in AppShopBundle\Resources\config\services.yml**

```
services:
    app_shop.service:
        class: AppShopBundle\Service\AppShopService
        arguments: 
            - "@security.token_storage"
            - ...

    app_shop.twig_extension:
        class: AppShopBundle\Twig\AppShopExtension
        arguments: 
          - "@app_shop.service"
        tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

After icluding the `Twig Extension`, `AppShopService` and its method `userHasPurchases` does not work any more. Problem is, that the constructor of `AppShopService` does not set `user` anymore since `$tokenStorage->getToken()` now returns `null`.

How is this possible? I have changed nothing except including the `Twig Extension`. As soon as I remove the `Twig Extension` from `services.yml` everything works correctly again.

My only guess is, that the creation fo the `Twig Extension` is done before any security. But why?

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: In general, you don't want to get the user in the constructor.  You never really know if the security component has done it's thing before your object is created.  So just add a MyService::getUser and call it whenever it is needed.  Save yourself some timing headaches.

Comment: don't interact with the tokenStorage in the constructor but only in the `userHasPurchases``  method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't interact with the tokenStorage in the constructor but only in the `userHasPurchases` method.

```
namespace AppShopBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
...

class AppShopService {
    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, ...) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function userHasPurchases(User $user) {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken() ? $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;
        $result = $user...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot! This indeed solves the problem. But why? I understand that timing can be an issue, but is security/templating/etc done async? I use `$this->user =$this->tokenStorage->getToken() ? $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;` in several other services as well, without any problem so far. What is so special in this case?

Comment: hi @AndreiHerford it depends of the lifecycle of the service but i don't find any resources about it at the moment. Usually I interact with the service only when i need it, and never in the constructor of the service itself  so the service can be stateless (avoid mutable call attribute). Hope this help